# Create .bat to do a task at a certain time

Tags: windows-8, command-line, batch, scheduled-tasks

I'd like to create a .bat file in Windows 8.1 that does a task (specifically, close a program/kill a process) at a certain time.

I  usually use the command line (which, I believe, works as a .bat file, right?) to shutdown the computer after some time, with the command
`shutdown -s -f -t [seconds]`. Is there a similar way to do this with the `taskkill` command? All the solutions I've encountered involve using the Task Scheduler, which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: So you want to execute a task (`taskkill`) at a specific time, but you want to avoid using the built in Windows scheduler?

Comment: Task Scheduler is your best friend for these situations... Not what you want to hear, but it's the preferred Microsoft way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple command to do what you need is timeout command

```
(your command)

TIMEOUT 5

your TASKKILL command
```

where 5 is time in second

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

This is a very similar question to this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735285/how-to-wait-in-a-batch-script

here is the answer that one person gave:

> You can ping an address that surely doesn't exist and specify the desired timeout:
>
> ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 10000 > nul
> And since the address does not exists, it'll wait 10,000 ms (10 seconds) and returns.

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
ping -n 5 127.0.0.1 > nul
```

In the batch at the place where you want to wait and execute the `taskkill` afterwards. Where `-n 5` is the time in seconds to wait **+1** because ping waits between pings. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1672350/2373114)